# How to make array wait for nested loops to complete before returning

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, arrays, nested-loops

I have the following nested loop function which loops through nested JSON objects. It gathers the data and adds each iteration to an array and each array will be a row of data in a MySql database.

Only the final full iterated data is being added to the MySql database though, so I believe either the data is being saved over previous data in the loop, or else the array variable is not waiting for all of the data? I'm not sure

```
    function getCategories(jsonContent) {
        var values = [];
            try {
                for(let i=0; i<jsonContent.length; i++) {
                    if (jsonContent[i].subcategories) {
                        var subcat = jsonContent[i].subcategories.length;

                        for (let n=0; n<subcat; n++) {
                            if(jsonContent[i].subcategories[n].facetValueData) {
                                var subsubcat = jsonContent[i].subcategories[n].facetValueData.length;

                                for (let p=0; p<subsubcat; p++) {
                                    var products = jsonContent[i].subcategories[n].facetValueData[p].productData.length
                                    for (let f=0; f<products; f++) {
                                        
                                        var productDataFinal = jsonContent[i].subcategories[n].facetValueData[p].productData[f]
                                        values.push([   
                                            0,
                                            jsonContent[i].id, jsonContent[i].categoryName, 
                                            jsonContent[i].subcategories[n].name, jsonContent[i].subcategories[n].code, 
                                            jsonContent[i].subcategories[n].facetValueData[p].name, jsonContent[i].subcategories[n].facetValueData[p].code,
                                            productDataFinal.productDisplayName, productDataFinal.code, 
                                            productDataFinal.url, productDataFinal.imageUrl,
                                            productDataFinal.price.value, productDataFinal.originPrice.value, 
                                            productDataFinal.price.currencyIso, productDataFinal.inStock,
                                            productDataFinal.newProduct,
                                        ])
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                console.log(`No facetvalue data found at ${jsonContent[i]}`)
                        }
                    } 
                    } else {
                        console.log(`No subcats found at ${jsonContent[i]}`)
                }
            }
            return values;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
```

The data is then added to the database with this:

```
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {console.log("Error adconnecting to db" + err)}
        else {console.log("Connected!")}

        let valueData = getCategories(jsonContent)

        let sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO data VALUES ?'
        con.query(sqlQuery, [valueData], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {console.log("Error adding to db" + err)}
            else {console.log("Added to table"+result)}
    });
  });
```

if I add the following code just above the `return values;` line to write the values array to a seperate json file, all of the correct arrays of data are added to the file, so they must get lost along the way to the database somehow?

```
fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(values, null, 2), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err)
                }
                console.log(`\n ${parsedResults.length} Results exported successfully to ${outputFile}\n`)
            })
```

Comment: what if you add a `console.log(values)` above your `return values;` in your `getCategories` function? do you see all the results that you want? you are doing a `for-loop` and it is a blocking action. it should bring all the correct values.

Comment: Yes all of the correct arrays are logged to console, theyre just not adding to the database for some reason. I think they are copying over the original values rather than appending under them

Comment: @tomj1596 Maybe you need to remove array constructor in this line: `con.query(sqlQuery, [valueData], function (err, result)` like this: `con.query(sqlQuery, valueData, function (err, result)`? Because your `con.query` gets "array of array of array" as input... seems strange.

Comment: when I do that I get the following error: ```Error adding to dbError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 0, 'Beauty', 'Skincare', '/beauty/skin-care', 'Lotion Serum & Essence', '/bea' at line 1```

Comment: @tomj1596 Wait a second... What is the first zero in your `values` array? I mean this part: `values.push([0,`. Is it an ID to the resulting table? So you are adding always the line with ID=0? If so, then did you check this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/42071/how-to-force-mysql-to-take-0-as-a-valid-auto-increment-value ?

Comment: Thank you that solved it for me.